# Upsampling and plotting a frequency domain signal

Tags: matlab, fft, sample

I want to upsample by 5 a signal in frequency domain, and then plot (stem) it. I figured how to upsample,

```
Fk=(1/5)*upsample(ak_new,5);
```

now this creates a vector that is 5 times bigger than the original one, and I need to take the inverse Fourier series of this signal

```
Fn=(Fk*(exp((1i*2*pi/N*n'*n))));
```

where `n` is a sample vector `(-1000:1000)`, as you can see, I can't make the transformation since `n` is not the same size as `Fk` anymore. How can I solve this?

Comment: did you try to multiply n and N by 5?

Comment: I tried upscaling 'n' itself and multiplying N by 5, but it doesn't work. I should get a "shrink" in time- the discreet lines should be denser, and they're not

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot your upsampled signal in frequency domain, on a similarly "upsampled" frequency vector.

If your initial frequency vector was `-1000, -999, -998 ...`, now it should be `-1000, -999.8, -999.6`.

Here is a simple example:

```
Fs = 2000;              % Sampling frequency                    
T = 1/Fs;               % Sampling period       
L = 2000;               % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;          % Time vector

S = sin(2*pi*400*t);    % Signal

Y = fft(S);
ak_new = fftshift(abs(Y/L));        % Initial signal in frequency domain
Fk = upsample(ak_new,5);            % Upsampled signal

f   = (Fs/L)*(-L/2:  1  :L/2-1);    % Initial frequency vector
fup = (Fs/L)*(-L/2:(1/5):L/2-1/5);  % Upsampled frequency vector

subplot(2, 1, 1);
stem(f, ak_new);
title('Before upsampling');

subplot(2, 1, 2);
stem(fup, Fk);
title('After upsampling');
```

[image: upsampling]